# Is there a way to point a fallback intent to an actual intent in api.ai?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

Bear with me on this one.  I will try to explain in the simplest way possible.  I have built a chatbot using API.AI.  The tree below is a simple and rough representation of how the flow goes.  First 2 levels are straightforward, it just asks simple questions then it branches out to different paths.  As you can see also, that the endpoint is all the same.

The question here is that with a common endpoint and having multiple yes/no fallback intents, is there a way to link the fallback intents to ***one*** common intent?

```
Get name
└── Get email address
    ├── [johndoe@email.com]
    └── Does not give email address
        ├── Know more about person
        │   ├── About short description
        │   │   └── Dont want to know more
        │   │       ├── Read more
        │   │       └── Want to connect with person?
        │   │           ├── Show email address
        │   │           └── Goodbye            
        │   ├── Coding short description
        │   │   └── Dont want to know more
        │   │       ├── Read more
        │   │       └── Want to connect with person?
        │   │           ├── Show email address
        │   │           └── Goodbye
        │   ├── Achievements short description
        │   │   └── Dont want to know more
        │   │       ├── Read more
        │   │       └── Want to connect with person?
        │   │           ├── Show email address
        │   │           └── Goodbye
        │   └── Skills short description
        │   │   └── Dont want to know more
        │   │       ├── Read more
        │   │       └── Want to connect with person?
        │   │           ├── Show email address
        │   │           └── Goodbye
        └── Want to connect with person?
            ├── Show email address
            └── Goodbye
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume by the structure you've given that you're using FollowUpIntents, one way to group multiple intents to one fallback intent is using a contextOut that's the same for all the endpoints you'd like to match the fallback to.

FollowUp intents actually construct their flow with contexts in the same way, however, you can do this yourself too ofcourse.

so in the following intents:

```
│   ├── Coding short description
│   ├── Achievements short description
│   └── Skills short description
```

You simply set the contextout of these intents to something like "contextFallback".

In:

```
Dont want to know more
```

You simply set the contextIn as "contextFallback". This way, every time you trigger one of the contexts that set the context out, you can trigger and branch to the "Dont want to know more" intent. Resulting in one intent (instead of the 4 intents that do the same as per your example)

I hope I understood your question properly, otherwise I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That sounds about right.  That was my initial build.  The user expression is "no" and but somehow it's not being recognized and Small Talk is being triggered instead.  That's why I had to resort back to fallbackIntent.

Comment: That's not how it supposed to work, from my experience (and i've tested this with smallTalk turned on), smallTalk should only trigger if it doesn't match any of the intents (and the required contextIn for that particular intent). Perhaps you could clarify your setup with a few screenshots. (an intent, the fallback intent, overview and where you think it doesn't do as you want it to do) hopefully I can help you better that way and provide some insights in how I'd set this up.